# containsKey doesn't match the urls

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I am trying to  store hyperlink as a key in map , i am using multimap

```
 private Map<String, List<String>> record=new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

and i am using following way to check whether the hyperlink is already exist in the map or not

```
 record.containsKey(url)
```

But even if the url is exist in a map , it is returning false for the same url which is already there in the map. so how can i solve this issue

the link i am storing is

```
   http://101.13.20.343/test/wav/uploads/372.wav
```

Comment: There is no reason why it would not work. Try and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that replicates your issue.

Comment: Works just fine: http://ideone.com/DASDf

Comment: Try printing your map keys with prefixed and suffixed with ---key---  and if you see a space between them, then the blank space will be the issue.

Comment: Hell , i was adding keys inside a inner loop so thts why it was create a new object every time my mistake but +1 for all the efforts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> record=new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        record.put("http://101.13.20.343/test/wav/uploads/372.wav", new ArrayList<String>());
        System.out.println(record.containsKey("http://101.13.20.343/test/wav/uploads/372.wav"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you trim the whitespaces at each end? In some cases, this might be it?